# Context Menu Command not Working

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, command, contextmenu

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app and I have some problems with a `ContextMenu` of a `List Box`. I use the toolkit `ContextMenu` in the `ListBoxItemTemplate` as follow:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
        <Grid Height="50" Background="#11414141"
            Margin="0,1,0,1">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove Transaction" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveTappedElementCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="{Binding IsIncome, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"/>-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFFB7C26"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd/MM}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="6,0,6,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                Text="{Binding Capitolo}" 
                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=C}"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Foreground="{Binding IsIncome, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    FontSize="25"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsIncome, Converter={StaticResource TypeToSignStringConverter}}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Foreground="{Binding IsIncome, Converter={StaticResource TypeToColorConverter}}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"                               
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="25"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I'm using MVVM pattern, so I tried to bind Command propery of the `MenuItem` to an `ICommand` of the ViewModel. But when I click on the `MenuItem` of the context menu, nothing happens, the command is not fired and I can't figure out the reason. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in your binding:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveTappedElementCommand}"
```

This will *not* look for the `RemoveTappedElementCommand` on the top-level DataContext, but will instead look for the property `DataContext` on your item view model.
To realy bind to the DataContext of the Page/Control contatining the ListBox, give that item a name

```
x:Name="Root"
```

and expand your binding:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.RemoveTappedElementCommand}"
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right! Thanks! I thought that DataContext were inherited from the parents controls! So in the item template the DataContext is automatically set to the current item of the collection. Effectively when you think about it, you use the binding in the form `{Binding itemPropertyName}` so the DataContext is the item...
Thanks a lot!